# Combine multiple MySQL rows into one row

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

Here's what I am currently getting from my query:

| row_no | prospect | hot | contract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | Joe | *null* |
| 1 | John | *null* | *null* |
| 1 | *null* | *null* | Sam |

I Am trying to get:

| row_no | prospect | hot | contract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Joe | Sam |

I cannot use concate because I still need separate columns

Here's what I have so far...
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e7aab240b40e40955bac44f616d7f3d7

**Please note:** Ultimately, there will be 7 columns, but a varying amount of rows (ie. the **prospect** column may have 20 records, where the **contract** column may only have four or five.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
WITH CTE_tbl AS
(
  SELECT lead_type,firstname, last_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY lead_type order by lead_type Desc) as row_no
  FROM leads
) 
SELECT row_no,
       MAX(case when  lead_type = 'prospect' then firstname end) prospect,
       MAX(case when  lead_type = 'hot' then firstname end) hot,
       MAX(case when  lead_type = 'contract' then firstname end) contract
FROM CTE_tbl
GROUP BY row_no
ORDER BY row_no
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=98b6ec9d46e4189ec1b3d8f01c2f76bb).
Results:

| row_no | prospect | hot | contract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Joe | Sam |
| 2 | Mario | Autumn | null |
| 3 | Frank | null | null |
| 4 | Mary | null | null |
| 5 | Steve | null | null |

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you!