# How to Load Data From Mysql Table to as Month wise Column

Tags: c#, mysql

Table and date:

| EntryID | Empno | Empname | Date | Receivable | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EmpNo4 | Zulfiqar | Baloch | 2022-05-07 | 15000 | Received |
| EmpNo4 | Zulfiqar | Baloch | 2022-04-07 | 15000 | Received |
| EmpNo4 | Zulfiqar | Baloch | 2022-03-07 | 15000 | Received |
| EmpNo3 | Gul | Ahmed | 2022-05-07 | 20000 | Received |
| EmpNo3 | Gul | Ahmed | 2022-04-07 | 20000 | Received |
| EmpNo3 | Gul | Ahmed | 2022-03-07 | 20000 | Received |
| EmpNo3 | Gul | Ahmed | 2022-02-07 | 20000 | Received |
| EmpNo3 | Gul | Ahmed | 2022-01-07 | 20000 | Received |
| EmpNo4 | Zulfiqar | Baloch | 2022-02-07 | 15000 | Received |
| EmpNo4 | Zulfiqar | Baloch | 2022-01-07 | 15000 | Received |

I have this data in a table and I want to load it in C# Datagridview as columns like EmpNo, Name, January, February, March etc
Meaning one persons data be showed horizontally in month wise column.
Please Help if you can.

Query I tried ?:

I tried multiple queries with that i got this result

| Employee No | Name | Jan | Feb | Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EmpNo3 | Gul Ahmed | 20000 |  |  |
| EmpNo3 | Gul Ahmed |  | 20000 |  |
| EmpNo3 | Gul Ahmed |  |  | 20000 |

It creates a new row for each month I want is all the months for a person in single row.

Comment: The show us your attempts so which comete error message

Comment: Would be nice to have your table column names and your query.

Comment: @bonCodigo Column Names are EntryID, Empno, Empname, Date, Receivable, Status and 
these are the queries i used
"Select empno as 'Employee No',Name, Receivable as 'Feb' from 360data.salarylhr where empno = '" + this.EmpNotxt.Text + "' and Date >= '" + "2022-02-01" + "'and Date <= '" + "2022-02-28" + "'"
"Select empno as 'Employee No',Name, Receivable as 'Mar' from 360data.salarylhr where empno = '" + this.EmpNotxt.Text + "' and Date >= '" + "2022-03-01" + "'and Date <= '" + "2022-03-31" + "'"

Comment: @bonCodigo 
picture link of the result   https://ibb.co/DkRcj1v

Comment: Please update your question with the info in the comment. Add the table column names and query to your question. Also take a look at the [guidelines that shows how to produce a minimal example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You may also provide a sqlfiddle or [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) with your table schema for sql related questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pivot table returns multiple rows with NULLs, are not grouped on one row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54947611/pivot-table-returns-multiple-rows-with-nulls-are-not-grouped-on-one-row)  or [MySQL get multiple rows into columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65980647/combine-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-row)

Comment: @Luuk i have tried this please check if you can resolve the issue of duplication of Name
https://dbfiddle.uk/2GoXrlA_

Comment: Why are you doing `GROUP BY row_no` ?  When you need a unique name in your result, do a group by Name.  (see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/1n59dHtn))   P.S. The ROW_NUMBER is useless in this, and should (or can) be removed...